# Purpose of the saved user ID

Tags: c, linux, unix

Running a program with the  [setuid()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setuid.2.html) bit set is the same thing as running it as the owner of that program. After execution programs usually exit, so why do we have to switch back to the real user ID?

Also, the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_identifier#Saved_user_ID) article states that:

> The saved user ID (suid) is used when a program running with elevated privileges needs to do some unprivileged work temporarily.

Why is that though? Why would a privileged process lower its privileges, I can't wrap my head around this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is best to do as much as possible with lower privileges. That way the OS protects you from doing stupid things.

Do as little as possible as root. Many people have logged in as root and really messed things up.

Comment: if a process running as root by root needs to do some unprivileged task, will it pick an id at random?

Comment: No it will not - You have to select the appropriate user id

Comment: operating as root (i.e. logged in as root) means you are completely free to do anything with absolute freedom.  Including screw-up.  `sudo` run from a non-root account is also dangerous for the same reason, although for a shorter period of time.

Comment: but in which cases would a root process drop its privileges?

Comment: It should do so whenever it does not need root privileges. Basically have a good excuse to be using root.

Comment: It will not drop its privileges on its own volition.  Wise administrators will often place themselves in a hyper-aware state during the time they are logged in as root while doing specific tasks, knowing they are walking a tightrope without a net, then, continuing their work with a lower privileged account for the remainder of the session.  Being root is dangerous and does not suffer fools.  i.e. when you are tired, or find your mind is drifting, logout of root and walk away for awhile.

Comment: @ryyker  one more thing, I just compiled  a program  (as root) and enabled the setuid bit on it, then I executed as another user, however *ps* is showing that this unprivileged user is who is executing the program, shouldn't it be showing root though? (because of setuid)

Comment: Why are you compiling stuff as root?

Comment: @EdHeal I'm just trying to understand how setuid() works

Comment: @Trey - As I said earlier - do as little as possible as root. You do not need to compile code as root. The only bit is setting the setuid bit. Become root, set the bit on the file, go back to normal.

Answer (score 7):

Expanding on the purpose of the saved user ID, it also allows a process that was running with elevated privileges and subsequently dropped them to go back to the elevated privileges if needed.

Suppose a user with ID 1001 runs a setuid-root program.  At program startup, the various user IDs are set as follows:

- real UID: 1001
- effective UID: 0
- saved UID: 0

Setting the saved user ID to the effective user ID at startup allows the user to go back to this user ID whenever it is needed.

At this point the program has root priviliges.  The program can then do the following:

```
// perform privileged commands
seteuid(1001);   // drop privileges, euid is now 1001
// perform unprivileged commands
seteuid(0);    // raise privileges, euid is now 0, allowed because saved UID is 0
// perform more privileged commands
seteuid(1001);   // drop privileges, euid is now 1001
// perform more unprivileged commands
```

Answer (score 4):

> Why would a privileged process lower its privileges, I can't wrap my head around this.

Several reasons:

- First and foremost: so that the process knows what user launched it! Otherwise, it'd have no way of knowing -- there is no system call to explicitly get the UID of another process. (There is procfs, but that's nonstandard and unreliable.)
- As others have mentioned, for safety. Dropping privileges limits the damage that can be done by a malfunctioning setuid-root program. (For instance, a web server will typically `bind` to a socket on port 80 while running as root, then set its UID/GID to a service user before serving any content.)
- So that files created by the setuid-root process are created as owned by the user that launched the process, not by root.
- In some situations, root can have *less* capabilities than non-root user IDs. One example is on NFS -- UID 0 is typically mapped to "nobody" on NFS servers, so processes running as root do not have the ability to read or modify all files on an NFS share.